# Convert Anonymous java object types to JSON using GSon

Tags: java, json, gson

is there any possibility to serialize anonymous object type to JSON using Gson or  any else library  on JAVA ?

```
Object objResult = new Object() {
                boolean success = true;
                String  email="mail@gmail.com";
            };

String jsonstr = gson.toJson(objResult);
```

In this example, the string jsonstr returns a null value.

Comment: Well, it's not really "anonymous", since the object carries its identity with it.  But I don't know of a kit that will crack it.  (Of course, one could easily write the code to produce the Map you need and serialize that -- far easier than "cracking" the class.)

Comment: so there is no possibility :p

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Gson doesn't support that feature. From the [user guide](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md)

> Fields corresponding to the outer classes in  inner classes, anonymous
> classes, and local classes are ignored and not included in
> serialization or deserialization

You can use a `Class` (or other `Type`) representing the superclass of the anonymous type to describe what to serialize using the overloaded [`toJson(Object, Type)`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.6/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/Gson.html#toJson(java.lang.Object,java.lang.reflect.Type)) method, but you'll still lose any new fields defined in the anonymous subclass. (Obviously, with `Object`, this does nothing, since `Object` has no fields.)

Comment: This got me on a map: `new HashMap<String, Object>() {{put("key", "value");}}` serialized to null.

Answer (score 1):

If you use MyClass(){{}} inline syntax use Gson.toJson(obj, type) overloaded method.

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass(){{}};
new Gson.toJson(obj, obj.getClass().getSuperclass())
```

Anonymous class names contains $ letter. So to get exact class use

```
Type type = obj.getClass();
while(type.toString.Contains("$")) type = ((Class)type).getSuperclass();
new Gson.toJson(obj, type);
```

Comment: This only works for a single depth. `MyClass(){{ this.other = MyOtherClass() {{}}; }}` will still not work.