# Using GSON to parse a JSON array from Ajax request

Tags: java, arrays, json, ajax, gson

my json string is:

```
[{"name":"51","value":"0"},{"name":"52","value":"0"},{"name":"53","value":"5"},{"name":"54","value":"1"},{"name":"106","value":"0"},{"name":"107","value":"0"},{"name":"108","value":"3"}]
```

I am trying to do:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
    class Wrapper{
        String name;
        String value;       
    }
Wrapper[] arr = gson.fromJson(request.getParameter("data"), Wrapper[].class);
```

And then:

```
for (Wrapper arr1 : arr) {
        if(Long.parseLong(arr1.value)!=0){
            listeProduits.add(ServiceMetier.getProduitById(Long.parseLong(arr1.name)));
            listeQuantites.add(Long.parseLong(arr1.value));
        }
    }
```

But I am always getting:

```
May 08, 2017 11:32:06 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve 
invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [ActionServlet] in context with path 
[/Gustatif_Web] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

The null pointer is on arr1.
What am I doing wrong with my json parsing?

Edit:
one problem was having the Wrapper class inside the method, another problem was deeper within the dependencies to another project.

Comment: Have your tried debugging? Debugging helps.

Comment: when debugging i see that the variable arr is an array of 7 elements, but the variable arr[1] is null

Comment: A duplicate of [Convert Anonymous java object types to JSON using GSon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26791752/convert-anonymous-java-object-types-to-json-using-gson) . Just move your `Wrapper` class **out** of the method you have currently it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have try it ; your code has a little error; you must create a new java class－－ Wrapper，do not be the inner class of this Method.
[image]